# Dropdown sub menu in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to implement dropdown sub menu in angular 2? I have this code:

```
<button md-icon-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="topPosition color-md-icon">
  <md-icon>more_vert</md-icon>
</button>
<md-menu #menu="mdMenu">
  <button (click)="fi()" md-menu-item>
    <md-icon>cloud</md-icon>
    <span>1</span>
  </button>
  <button md-menu-item>
    <md-icon>cloud</md-icon>
    <span>2</span>
  </button>
  <button md-menu-item>
    <md-icon>cloud</md-icon>
    <span>3</span>
  </button>
  <md-divider></md-divider>
  <button md-menu-item>
    <md-icon>perm_data_setting</md-icon>
    <span>4</span>
  </button>
</md-menu>
```

Maybe add some custom function? Or something else? I see this material sub menu for angularjs (https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/menuBar), like File - New, and then open new sub-menu.

Comment: Hello where you able to find a solution? I am trying to implement the same functionality

Comment: @D-W-A Hi, yes, i found ngx-bootstrap - http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/